# Why there is no insert query in jpql

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql, dropwizard

I am using dropwizard hibernate and there I am using `@NamedQuery()`
I didn't find any source to put my data into my database

Answer (score 0):

You can do INSERT with HQL (Hibernate Query Language):

> **Statement types**
>
> Both HQL and JPQL allow SELECT, UPDATE and DELETE statements to be
>   performed. HQL additionally allows INSERT statements, in a form
>   similar to a SQL INSERT FROM SELECT.

See: [HQL and JPQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/query/hql/HQL.html)

Answer (score 0):

To put data into the database the Hibernate way use the [`EntityManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) interface. It has two methods to put data into the database:

```
<T> T merge(T entity)

void persist(Object entity)
```